# Unicode surrogate pairs in PHP

Tags: php, unicode, emoji

I am attempting to convert a two character country code, such as GB, to the emoji flag for that country. The emoji flag is created by combining the code points for the two characters together. I am able to generate these code points in UTF-16 using the following code in PHP:

```
"\u".dechex(127397 + ord("G"));
```

However, to generate the emoji character in PHP 5.x, I need to use the surrogate pair for that code point. In this example, `\u1F1EC` would need to be converted into `\uD83C\uDDEC`. I am looking for a function that can make this conversion for me.

Comment: The character codes won't change... why not do a lookup array?

Comment: I had some hopes there would just be a quick function to do this, but the lookup array might be the quickest route instead.

Comment: [Algorithm is known well](http://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/unicode_encodings.html#surrogates)…

Comment: I had found that previously, but I am specifically looking for PHP code for this same algorithm and have not found it. I tried converting it myself to no avail.